# Python os.rename "\" and "/" cross-platform issue

Tags: windows, python-2.7, unix, cross-platform

I'm trying to make a cross-platform program that move a file to a folder inside the user home folder, like this:

```
os.rename(file_var, destination_folder)
```

but I can't make it work because I need to put the file name inside the destination var, and the problem is the Windows "\"

what are my options?

Comment: So use the `os.path` module to handle paths in a cross-platform manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:
for example you want this path:

```
'+pathfile+'/output/log.txt'
```

instead of typing a string, join them like this:

```
os.path.join(pathfile,"output","log.txt")
```

NOTE:

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020267/how-to-make-a-python-or-perl-script-portable-to-both-linux-and-windows) post `/` works both in `windows` and `linux`, i always use `os.path.join()`