# Where cgi script's "#!/usr/ " points to?

Tags: python, apache, cgi, cgi-bin

First of all I know The path points to the executable file. What I'm asking is in which directory it points?

I'm very new at python. I works on PHP, and now I'm giving Python a try.
I'm configuring my apache-2.2 with python. I have configured my cgi-bin directory. My problem is I installed Python2.7 on a very different location, and dont know how to  point that "#!usr/" path to the exact location where python.exe is.

Thanks,

Kamil

Comment: I know what you said. What I'm saying is,  my apache installed in "c:/programfiles/apache2.2/" and python installed in "E:/python-installed/" now how can i call python.exe from cgi script?

Comment: Assuming the path `E:/python-installed` contains your python.exe binary, the solution below should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory it points to is... `/usr/`? you define the path and THEN the executable, like so: `#!/usr/bin/python3` where `python3` is the executable and the path is `/usr/bin/`, standard python directory if you think about it.. most binaries are stored in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

I'm assuming you're rocking a windows machine tho since you mentioned .exe.
So do: `#!E:/python-installed/python.exe -u`

Some docs:

- http://www.imladris.com/Scripts/PythonForWindows.html

Answer (score 0):

Provided running `python` or `python2` does the right thing (preferably test this as the user the cgi script will run as if you can), the convention is to use the program `env` - which can search `$PATH` for an executable instead of hard coding a path. `env` is a standard program on any Unix-like system, which is *always* in /usr/bin unless your base system is very strange, so you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

According to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3559650/779200), this would cause the line to be *ignored* on a Windows machine, which may be what you want - it will cause Apache to revert to other ways to find an appropriate interpreter, which seems to include the value of a registry key (at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cgi\Shell\ExecCGI\Command`for cgi files, and change the extension as appropriate), and likely includes Windows' standard lookup rules if that key is unset.