# How to automatically resolve `.xyz` extension files to `#!C:\perl\perl.exe` without adding this in first line of them

Tags: apache, perl, wamp, wampserver

On Windiws machine (using Wampserver or whatever, using perl or python), when I use such approach:

```
#!C:\perl\perl.exe 
print "hi"
```

and when I open `localhost/file.pl` , it works well. But If i remove first line (path to `.exe`), it doesn't.

Is there any way (either with `htaccess` or `httpd.conf`) , so without need of that first line in each `.pl` file,  they were resolved to that path automatically?

Comment: Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036577/how-do-i-ignore-the-perl-shebang-on-windows-with-apache-2

Comment: @Jigar I didn't even know that was named `shebang` , thanks !

Comment: What you need to do is simply make your Server ignore the shebang `#!C:\perl\perl.exe`

Comment: @MobrineHayde so, it will use the path whatever is set in Windows automatically (which was created during perl installations), right? thanks!